# Mac OSX Catalina - Safari won't download files, not enough free space when plenty

Tags: download, safari, macos-catalina

I've had a search on the forums and the internet but couldn't find an answer to my issue.

Just updated my OSX to Catalina. I'm having a problem with Safari, when I try and download a file it tells me that there isn't enough space and to delete files. My SSD and my removable volume have more than enough space. As I only have a 128gb Macbook Pro I use an SD card as an overflow and this is where my download folder directs to. If I download using 'download file as..' and select the main SSD, it downloads fine. It just won't let me access the SD card. Chrome works fine.

I know that apps have been asking to access the removable volume, but to my knowledge, Safari has never asked permission. I've found how to add permission to for apps to access removable volumes in the privacy settings, but I cannot add safari to this list.

I've clicked the padlock and given permission but the + symbol is greyed out and I cannot drag the app from the applications folder to the window.

If somebody could point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Safari has never asked permission --> There you go. I faced this same issues on brand new Catalina. I tried again and Safari asked permission.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it as follows:

- do "get info" on the downloads folder. You will see on users & groups a user "fetching" or something similar, but not your user name in the list.
- click on the lock item next to the list and remove that user.
- click on the + to add your name to the list.
- close the lock.

Sorry if I got some details wrong. At work I'm enjoying Windows :)

Comment: Sorry, not the same for me. Sorry for the delay. I don't get notifications. I just see my name, with read/write access and everyone. with read. I tried changing everyone to read/write access. But no success!!